# Rails search form that can search for many attributes of multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search-form

I am creating a Rails application in which a user can post a Link to a live website they have on the web, as well as the content of the site and the programming language it was coded in.

I am trying to create a single search form that can search for a few things:

(1) The URL of posted link
(2) Programming language
(3) User name

I have both a link and a user model.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

    def self.search(search)
        where("language LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
        where("url LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :links

def self.search(search)
    where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
end
```

My User and Link controller index methods are as follows:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
    @links = Link.search(params[:link])
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @users = User.search(params[:user])
end
```

How would I go about delegating all search duties to a single search bar. In essence I would just like to have the search bar be able to search for the 3 attributes I mentioned above. I was planning on placing it in the index/layouts/application.html.erb folder.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: as far, as I understood, you need single page where you want search users and links. Right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood right:

you should crate Controller for search page, for example `SearchController` with only `index` action.

Than create model something like Search.rb

```
Search = Struct.new(:search_text) do
  def run
    users = User.where(name: search_text)
    links = Link.where(title: search_text)
    {users: users, links: links}
  end
end
```

controller:

```
def index
  @result = Search.run(params[:search])
end
```

so this is just example and you should amend it according to your needs.

**EDIT**

in view (slim):

```
b User List
ul
  - @result[:users].each |user|
    = user.name
```

and same for `links`

Comment: I am going to try this out. How would I render this in my view?

Answer (score 0):

One more involved solution that you may want to look at if you have tons of data is a `freetext search` within SQL.

It's possible to do it across multiple tables and integrate it with rails as described by [thoughtbot in their blog](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/implementing-multi-table-full-text-search-with-postgres).

Comment: sounds interesting i will look into that